# Python: Usage of anonymous list within dict of other values?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am asked to generate and also later read back a json object which looks like:

```
{"name":"somename",
   [{"id":123,"key1":"anydata"}, 
    {"id":345,"key1":"x","key3":"yz"}]}
```

Normally, I would use a python dict and convert it to/from json. Here however is the problem, that both, list and sub-dict are anonymous.

I think it is not possible to make a dict like this, is it?

Comment: By accident your code is valid Python.

Comment: This is not a valid JSON object!

Comment: Yes you're right. The outer structure is a dict, so the list needs a name.

Comment: Also doesn't seem like valid Python; the second item in the dict has no key, only the list..

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid json object but you can just add a key for the list part. Like:

```
{"name":"somename","value" : [{"id":123,"key1":"anydata"},{"id":345,"key1":"x","key3":"yz"}]}
```

Now this is a valid json string.

```
    >>> a = ast.literal_eval('{"name":"somename","value" : [{"id":123,"key1":"anydata"},{"id":345,"key1":"x","key3":"yz"}]}')

>>> print(a['name'])
>>> 'somename'

>>> print(a['value'][0]['id'])
>>> 123
```

For a variable list its is as simple as:

```
anon_list = [{"id":123,"key1":"anydata"},{"id":345,"key1":"x","key3":"yz"}]
a = {"name":"somename","value" : anon_list}


>>> print(a['name'])
>>> 'somename'

>>> print(a['value'][0]['id'])
>>> 123
```

Comment: If you are working with json use `json.loads` not `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: So it is not possible to use an anonymous list here. But if it is even not a valid json object, I can change it.

Comment: Sure it is possible. Check updated answer. @ErnieMur

Comment: But your solution is not what I asked. I wanted to have a list without using the keyword "value". Like the json example from me, even if it is not valid json.